# OpenShift Origin 3: "error: router could not be created"

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I am trying to create a router as described on https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/install_config/install/deploy_router.html#haproxy-router

However, when I run:

```
oadm router router --replicas=1 \
    --credentials='/etc/openshift/master/openshift-router.kubeconfig' \
    --service-account=router
```

I get the following error:

```
[root@openshift ~]# oadm router router --replicas=1 \
>     --credentials='/etc/openshift/master/openshift-router.kubeconfig' \
>     --service-account=router
error: router could not be created; the provided credentials "/etc/openshift/master/openshift-router.kubeconfig" could not be loaded: stat /etc/openshift/master/openshift-router.kubeconfig: no such file or directory
[root@openshift ~]#
```

Does anyone know what the problem is, and how I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using OpenShift Origin 1.1 which isn't exactly the same as OpenShift 3.1. The openshift-router.kubeconfig is in `/etc/origin/master/...`

Try to use the [documentation for origin](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/welcome/index.html) (1.1).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to move forward the correct version of the documentation.